# Taking the limit of a conjugation of a translation by homeomorphisms.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $h:B\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a homeomorphism from the open ball with center $0$ and radius $1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, given by $ h(x) = \frac{x}{(1-|x|)} $. Fixed arbitrarily $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be the translation $T(x) = x+a$. Consider the homeomorphism $\phi = h^{-1}Th:B \rightarrow B$. Proof that $\lim_{x \rightarrow b}\phi(x) = b \;\;\forall b \in \partial B $.

I'm having a hard time on how to proof this... I think I have to show that when $x \rightarrow b , \phi \rightarrow Id$, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All points $x$ of $B$ get mapped to a point along the ray formed by $0$ and $x$. The closer they are to the boundary, the further along that ray they get mapped.

Fix a $b\in \partial B$ and $\epsilon\gt 0$. All of the rays from $0$ that intersect the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ around $b$ form a cone that gets wider as the rays get further away from the origin. In particular, if you go far enough along the ray defined by $0$ and $b$, the cone will have a radius that is greater than |a|.

Therefore, choose $\delta\gt 0$ such that $|x-b|\lt\delta$ ensures that  $h(x)+a$ is contained in the cone. Then, since $h(x)+a$ is within the cone, $h^{-1}$ will  map $h(x)+a$ within the ball of radius $\epsilon$ around $b$.

Comment: You should also answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2870608.