# In respect to "Taking the limit of a conjugation of a translation by homeomorphisms."

Tags: real-analysis

I found the answer given in [Taking the limit of a conjugation of a translation by homeomorphisms.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527316/taking-the-limit-of-a-conjugation-of-a-translation-by-homeomorphisms) to be incomplete. Also, the last argument doesn't hold entirely: the point $y=h(x)+a$ may be in the cone but $h^{-1}(y)$, though it will still be in the cone, might not be in the ball around $b$. I'm also having a hard time finding the value for $\delta$

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the specific $\delta$, you just need to understand conceptually what is going on.

Consider the the open ball of radius $\epsilon, B_\epsilon$ around $b$. What is its image under $h$? It gets mapped to a subset $S_\epsilon$ of the cone that intersects $B_\epsilon$. $S_\epsilon$ contains all points beyond some boundary contained within the cone.

An open ball $B_\delta$ has the same properties. By choosing $\delta$ to be smaller that $\epsilon$, $h(B_\delta)$ will be contained in $h(B_\epsilon)$. Moreover, we can choose $\delta$ small enough so that $S_\delta+a\subset S_\epsilon$.

This gives us that $h^{-1}(S_\delta + a)\subset h^{-1}{S_\epsilon}\subset B_\epsilon$.